# The precision and recall of fasttext classification is None

Tags: fasttext

I use the [data](https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/fasttext-vectors/cooking.stackexchange.tar.gz) to classify. I didn't split the data. The following is my code:

```
classifier = fasttext.supervised('cooking.stackexchange.txt', 'model', 
label_prefix='__label__')
result = classifier.test('cooking.stackexchange.txt')
print('P@1: ', result.precision)
print('R@1: ', result.recall)
```

The result is: nan, nan

Why does it show this? Is there anything wrong?(I use the `fasttext` on windows10)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the latest version of fasttext installed, try something like this:

```
import fastText.FastText as fasttext

def print_results(N, p, r):
    print("N\t" + str(N))
    print("P@{}\t{:.3f}".format(1, p))
    print("R@{}\t{:.3f}".format(1, r))

classifier = fasttext.train_supervised('cooking.stackexchange.txt', epoch=5)
result = classifier.test('cooking.stackexchange.txt')
print_results(*result)

# =>
# Read 0M words
# Number of words:  16568
# Number of labels: 736
# Progress: 100.0% words/sec/thread:   58127 lr:  0.000000 loss:  9.808085 ETA:   0h 0m
# N 15404
# P@1   0.162
# R@1   0.070
```

[Here's another example](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/python/doc/examples/train_supervised.py) from the fasttext github project.